# Python character encoding at writing

Tags: python, encoding

My program is the follow:

```
#/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import os, sys

from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
location = geolocator.reverse("47, 17")
cim = location.raw['address']['country']

#cim = "Magyarország"

print(cim)
f = open('out.txt','w')
f.write(cim)
f.closed
```

The program writes the correct value (Magyarország) at line 12, but at line 14 there is error. ('ascii' codec can't encode character ... in position 10)

And it's interesting, because when I give the value of cim at line 10, both of writings work.

(I'm totally beginner at python)

Comment: `cim = u"Magyarország" ` try pls

Comment: Try explicitly encoding as unicode:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: @TolgahanÜZÜN: where does it say this is Python 2? The error shows they are using Python 3, and they didn't specify an encoding for the open file, so Python uses the system default. Here that default turns out to be ASCII.

Comment: @TolgahanÜZÜN: besides, the value came from an API, it is not a literal.

Comment: In the duplicate I talk about *reading*, but the same applies to *writing* to a file. Specify a suitable encoding for the file when opening: `open('out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8')` for example.

Comment: Tolgahan, and how can I specify an encoding for the file?

Comment: for f = open('out.txt', 'w', encoding='utf8') I get:    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: @MátéBrunner: so are you using Python 2 instead then? I was assuming Python 3 because you showed `cim = "Magyarország"` (no `u` prefix on the string).

Comment: @MátéBrunner: then use `from io import open` to get the Python 3 file I/O system, or encode your data explicitly with `f.write(cim.encode('utf8'))`.

Comment: The encode('utf8') works, thank you very much!

Comment: Anyway, i dont know, which version is this...